# TypeSafe Slick 1.0.1 - AutoInc and return inserted id

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using Scala 2.10.0, Play Framework 2.1.0, TypeSafe Slick 1.0.1 and play-slick 0.3.2.

I've created a set of Slick entities that work as expected. I'd like to add some logic in the Global.scala to create a basic set of database records on startup by overriding onStart.

I'm using the examples I've found online with a statement like this:

```
def forInsert = name ~ description ~ viewDesc ~ skinDesc <>({ t => PackageDescription(None, t._1, t._2, t._3, t._4)}, { (pd: PackageDescription) => Some((pd.name, pd.description, pd.viewDesc , pd.skinDesc ))})
```

And in Global.scala, I'm invoking it like this:

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
    DB.withSession {
      implicit session => {
        val packageDescId = PackageDescriptions.forInsert returning PackageDescription.id insert PackageDescription(None, "foo", "bar", "baz", "quux")
    }
}
```

When I do this in Global.scala 'returning' and 'insert' are not resolved as symbols. This works fine elsewhere. I've verified that I have all the same imports in both locations.

I'm assuming something isn't initialized at this point in the application or is this assumption false? If true, is there anyway to initialize what I need? Otherwise, is there a way to do what I want?

I'm just starting with both Scala and Play so some of my basic understanding may be lacking.

Comment: I'd also much appreciate if someone could explain the details of why this doesn't work as expected if it's impossible to do what I want as above.

Comment: I managed to get around the issue by adding imports scoped to my onStart method. I don't understand what is happening here. These same imports were at the file scope. Can anyone enlighten me, please? Or just point to the documentation that explains this.

Comment: Can you update your original post to show the changes you made to fix the issue as well as the imports that were declared at the top of the file?